# How to read local .json file and display data in Window Phone 7/8?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, json.net, windows-phone

I have tried couple of different methods, no luck yet. Note:In second if statement, I have entered long json string. However, I dont want to write long json string, instead, I want to read from json file.

```
    private void Pivot_LoadingPivotItem_1(object sender, PivotItemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if(e.Item == item1)
            {
                list1.Items.Clear();
                //string stopslist1 = @"[{""Name"":""Communication Sciences""},{""Name"":""Hope Lodge""},{""Name"":""Juniper-Poplar""}]";
                IsolatedStorageFile mysfile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                IsolatedStorageFileStream fs = mysfile.OpenFile(@"c:\users\prime\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\BullRunnertest3\BullRunnertest3\stopsA.json",FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                using (StreamReader re = new StreamReader(fs))
                {
                    string stopslist1 = re.ReadToEnd();
                }
                List<RouteStops> stops = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RouteStops>>(stopslist1);
                foreach(RouteStops em in stops)
                {
                    string name = em.Name;
                    list1.Items.Add(name);
                }
            }
            else if (e.Item == item2)
            {
                list2.Items.Clear();
                string stopslist2 = @"[{""Name"":""Computer Sciences""},{""Name"":""Hope for Lodge""},{""Name"":""Juniper and Poplar""}]";
                List<RouteStops> stops = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RouteStops>>(stopslist2);
                foreach (RouteStops em in stops)
                {
                    string name = em.Name;
                    list2.Items.Add(name);
                }
            }
            else......
```

Comment: you have any constraint of language. As F# already having json data provider to read. if you can dump json file to it will good.

Comment: no, I'm only using c#, do u have any advise for this? thnks

Comment: i think you got the answer. :), if still anything let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like you are trying to access the C:// drive on Windows phone...which does not exist.  Watch this video: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start-04-Files-and-Storage-on-Windows-Phone-8

to learn how to access files from local storage.